# open default browser with a post in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I know in delphi you can open the default browser with:

```
ShellExecute(self.WindowHandle,'open','www.website.com',nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

but I'm wanting to know if there is a way to automatically post data on the new opened brower window OR auto fill the login data (even in firefox, safari,etc)

Thanks

-Brad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can launch your browser with **OLE**, and use the `navigate` function to pass data and context to the url.

Open IE with OLE

```
MyBrowser := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application') as IWebBrowser2;
```

**Send data** to url

```
MyBrowser.Navigate('http://mysite.com', Flags, EmptyParam, PostData, Headers);
```

See here for an example of navigate function:
http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2408145&postcount=2

I hope this will help !

Comment: Didn't want IE only, but that might be my only choice. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add "Http://" before the name of the website, otherwise the OS doesn't know what application to open.

ShellExecute(Application.Handle,'open','http://www.bjmsoftware.com',nil,nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

works for me in a console application.

Comment: Correct, but his question was if he could specify what data should be POSTed or what fields to fill in.

Comment: @Lars, yep, saw that after hitting enter and tried to delete my own answer, but it just registers a "vote to delete"...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to POST data with the url or fill in fields using ShellExecute. There is no general API all browsers have to be remote controlled. Alternatives are using GET (encode in the url itself) or talking to specific browsers directly, like [TridenT suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842452/open-default-browser-with-a-post-in-delphi/2842831#2842831).