# Programmatically automating a web login

Tags: c#, winforms, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to create a C# Winforms application that will automatically log me into a site and download data. Specifically, I want to have my application automatically log into my online banking site, log me in, and download my transaction history. I can do this manually by logging in through a web browser and downloading it. I am trying to automate this. I know I probably need to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. Does anyone have an example of this or a framework of the steps I need to take to accomplish this? Keep in mind it will be secure site (https) and I will somehow have to collect session information and retain the session information for the duration of the session. Any thoughts?

Comment: i don't have high hopes for these aspirations. banks are very active in preventing exploits and they have, umm, all the money in the world to throw at it. You should take up knitting or something. It would be a better use of your time that trying to get past a bank site security. ;-)

Comment: I am not trying to do something illegal or hack or anything. I simply want to download MY own financial transactions to my computer so I can make a program that will track my spending. No different then what Microsoft Money or Quicken does

Comment: I wasn't implying that you were. I am saying that banks don't like and actively prevent this type of usage regardless of intent. You will not find joy here. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I'd just automate the web connection - see my answer here regarding automating GMail login, should be similar for your bank.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887244/how-do-i-login-to-gmail-via-internet-explorer-using-iwebbrowser-2/2887322#2887322

Comment: @bliss - gmail does not guard against automation. Banks do. Aggressively.

Comment: @codepost truthfully I've never had the need to attempt it, I think I'll give it a go though and see how I get on.  I'm kinda happy that they are doing this to be fair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), with that you can automate a sequence of interactions between user and browser.

You might be lucky in just being able to use web request and response to login, though many banks are making the move to javascript based login forms to obfuscate passwords in order to prevent trojans. See [Citibank (AU)](http://www.citibank.com.au/australia/signon1/) and [Westpac (AU)](https://online.westpac.com.au/esis/Login/SrvPage). It might be difficult enough to circumvent that you may have to resort to logging in manually and having a [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/) script automate the downloading.

For interests sake, it's also worth doing some research on banking trojans and how they handle the automated actions on behalf of a user. See [Zeus Banking Trojan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeus_%28trojan_horse%29).

Comment: How do programs such as Quicken do it? On Quicken, all I have to do is choose the name of my bank and it somehow automatically goes and fetches all my transaction history data?

Comment: Quicken must be using an API, check your bank to see if that API is public, or only allowed to be used by trusted software (that's paid the software development license)

Comment: I don't see one after doing a quick Google search. My guess is, Quicken and the bank must have some kind of negotiation deal that allows them to access bank accounts from their software.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace testSSL
{
    public partial class FormDownload : Form
    {
        private bool success;
        private const string filename = "file.txt";
        private const string url_string = "https://some.url.com";
        private Uri url;
    public FormDownload()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        success = false;
        url = new Uri(url_string);
    }

    public bool StartDownload()
    {
        this.ShowDialog();
        return success;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Activate();

        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
        label1.Text = "Working";

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

        //possible fix for running on w2k
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

        string user="user", pass="pass";
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        try
        {
            client.DownloadFileAsync(url, filename);
        }
        catch (Exception ue)
        {
            writeException(ue.Message);
        }

    }

    void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            writeException(e.Error.Message);
            success = false;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "Done";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            success = true;
        }
        this.Close();
    }

    void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void writeException(string ex)
    {
        ex = "Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Exception: " + ex + "\r\n";
        File.AppendAllText("downloadLog.txt", ex);
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred; it has been logged");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Nice touch with the code.  I just wanted to mention that this assumes a particular login mechanism, and is not a general solution.  From the NetworkCredential documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx: "The NetworkCredential  class is a base class that supplies credentials in password-based authentication schemes such as basic, digest, NTLM, and Kerberos. [...] This class does not support public key-based authentication methods such as Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client authentication."

Comment: Key thing to note here is the use of WebClient instead of HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. If Selenium was out, I'd prefer WebClient over HttpWebRequest/Response.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Open Financial Exchange](http://www.ofx.net/) specification. That is how Quicken/Money etc download transactions from your financial institutions.

Answer (score 0):

Browser automation (see link below) may be useful.

But remember... a login page is really a complex client application, capable of forming a complex, even encrypted web request.  So, by circumventing what you may perceive to be just an interface, you're actually circumventing an entire client app (which could formulate a simple HTTP POST or could perform some complex JavaScript manipulation followed by connection to a flash player and then a direct connection to a login server, but you get the point).  The login interface (really potentially a small app nowadays), could be updated drastically at any time, invalidating your automated login software.

So... you may want to use something that can automate it at a high level, working with the available interface (rather than circumventing it and attempting to formulate your own HTTP requests), and something like http://seleniumhq.org/ may help.

Just be careful writing software that blindly sends your credentials to a web page.  You're not there to monitor it when there's a hijacking of the page or the page suddenly isn't encrypted for some reason.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if it's impossible to connect to a banking website and download transactions programmatically  (I can assure you it's not--*almost* anything that can be done by the user can be done with code with enough ingenuity) how is it that iOS applications exist that can do just that? I know because I use one of these apps on a regular basis. Furthermore, I think Quickbooks Enterprise is capable of this (but don't quote me on that).

The only thing I can think of that would indicate that you might NOT be able to do it is if the iOS app creators have some sort of agreement with all the different banks and credit card companies. Somehow I doubt it, but I guess it's possible.

Comment: Its not impossible. It works through web services. These web services are created by the bank. Let's say you have an account at Wells Fargo bank. And you download the Wells Fargo bank app on your phone. The app on your phone communicates with Wells Fargo using their web service API. The problem is, not all banks make their API public. So you must use something like Fiddler to try to figure out how their API works.